# Saving an external file into Assets in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

In **Sharepoint Online**

Would it be possible to:

1- Every night (or at some other event)

2- Connect to `"http://someurl/file.csv"`

3- Save the file above to a local folder

Comment: Nothing at all ?